# What does kSecReturnPersistentRef do?

Tags: iphone, ios, keychain

Does it make a key chain item persistent between application runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a persistent reference is just that, a reference. It can be used as key to lookup the keychain item later, share the reference between applications that have access to shared keychain items, etc.

Answer (score 3):

@Plumenator You can search for a Keychain item later and in the search dictionary provide the value `kCFBooleanTrue` for the key `kSecReturnPersistentRef`. If an item is found, Keychain Services return a persistent reference to it. If `SecItemAdd()` successfully adds an item to the Keychain it will remain there as long as the Keychain exists (usually until a reset of the device) or `SecItemDelete()` deletes it.

To answer your second question: the key `kSecReturnPersistentRef` is called a return type key because you specify what the function `SecItemAdd()` or `SecItemCopyMatching()` should return to you. Possible flags are `kSecReturnPersistentRef`, `kSecReturnData`, `kSecReturnAttributes`, and `kSecReturnRef`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right. Check out [Keychain Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html):

> To obtain a persistent reference to
>   the added item (an object of type
>   CFDataRef), specify
>   kSecReturnPersistentRef with a value
>   of kCFBooleanTrue. Note that unlike
>   normal references, a persistent
>   reference may be stored on disk or
>   passed between processes.

Comment: 1) So, if i don't use this flag with SecAddItem(), will I lose that item after my app closes?

Comment: 2) Also, why is this flag called a return type constant? How can I use it with SecItemAdd()? It doesn't look like it belongs in the attributes argument of SecItemAdd().